# Per unit calculation

Tags: power-supply

### I DONT WANT THE SOLUTION

The question:

[image]

The answer:

[image]

I am only confused why he didn't take the three phase as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a mistake in the writing from the author. When dealing with balanced 3 phase systems, unless specified otherwise the given voltage and current values are all line values. Therefore, the square root of 3 must be in the denominator.